# Mikitex problem report during compilation from latex to dvi

Tags: compiling, report, dvi

I m facing a problem named as Mikitex problem report in some documents during compilation from latex to dvi. Copied information given below:

```
> MiKTeX Problem Report Message: The page could not be rendered. Data:
> This is dvips(k) 5.98 Copyright 2009 Radical Eye Software
> (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2020.02.03:1257' ->  C:\Program
> Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\dvips.exe: ! Couldn't find header
> file arial.pfb. Note that an absolute path or a relative path with ..
> are denied in -R2 mode.
> 
> Source: C:\work3\miktex-2.8\Libraries\MiKTeX\Dvi\DviPage.cpp Line:
> 1038 MiKTeX: 2.8 OS: Microsoft Windows 6.2 (build 9200) SystemAdmin:
> yes PowerUser: no Root0: C:\Users\Shahid
> Rafiq\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8 Root1: C:\Users\Shahid
> Rafiq\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.8 Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.8 Root3:
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8 UserInstall: C:\Users\Shahid
> Rafiq\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8 UserConfig: C:\Users\Shahid
> Rafiq\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8 UserData: C:\Users\Shahid
> Rafiq\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.8 CommonInstall: C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8 CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.8 CommonData:
> C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.8
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Judging from the little information you gave, looks like you are trying to use Arial as a font, but there is no such thing (on your system) that works with `dvips`. You could try `urw-arial` instead: https://ctan.org/pkg/urw-arial

Comment: You are probably including a graphic that refers to arial.

Comment: I have download from ctan.org but i do not know how to install or what i have to do with it.